# Using different SSL certificates for main domain & sub domains

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-cloudfront

My parent domain is https & also with www. This certificate is purchased from comodo. I have two other sub-domains which I want to make https too.

Can I get a wildcard SSL from AWS (CouldFront) and use it for those sub domains?

Please let me know.

Comment: Of course it is possible to use different certificates in many configurations, but what's absent from your question is a description of where your SSL is being terminated, and the question cannot be answered without this.  Are these all going through CloudFront?  If not, then where will you be installing these certs?

Comment: No. Cert. for domain.com & www.domain.com is purchased from Comodo and it is installed in server itslef and for only sub-domains we want it to be wild-card SSL certificate from ACM and going through CloudFront. Let me know if that would work! @Michael-sqlbot

Comment: You have an answer, below, that turns out to be correct, based on the setup you describe.  Based on this, you will need to configure CloudFront to whitelist the `Host:` header for forwarding to the origin server, otherwise the main site will be shown at every subdomain site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get a SSL certificate from AWS Cloud Front. You have to get that from AWS Amazon Certificate Manager (ACM). And yes you can get a wild card from AWS ACM and use that for your subdomains.

Comment: Yes, I meant ACM. So can I have two separate SSL certificates for a one domain?

Comment: Yes you can have 2 separate certificate for same domain.

Comment: Great! That answers my question. Thank you! :) Let me know if you do freelancing, I've some task for you.

Comment: Email me at piyu200594@gmail.com and please mark my answer correct